# Exception while sending/receiving msg over TCP using channel adapters

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting an exception while sending/receiving msg over TCP using channel adapters.
I am trying to send message to a socket using `TcpSendingMessageHandler` and receive message using `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter`. 
Here I am able to send message but getting exception while receiving msgs. Please let me know, what I am missing in the configuration.

My Configuration class:

```
    public class SampleTCPConnection {

    //Client Side
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "errorChannel")
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @Bean
    public ByteArrayCrLfSerializer connectionSerializeDeserialize(){
        return new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer(); 
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
    public MessageHandler sendToStreamHost() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler gateway = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(createConectionFactory());
        gateway.setClientMode(true);

        return  gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory createConectionFactory(){
        AbstractClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost",8002);
        cf.setSerializer(connectionSerializeDeserialize());
        return cf;
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTCPChannel", outputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public Object replyMessage(Message<String> msg) {
        return msg.getPayload();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public Object errorMessage(Message<String> msg) {
        return msg;
    }


    //server side

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpInGate(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory)  {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inGate = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        inGate.setOutputChannel(fromTCPSocket());
        return inGate;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory createServerConectionFactory(){
        AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8002);
        cf.setSerializer(connectionSerializeDeserialize());
        cf.setDeserializer(connectionSerializeDeserialize());
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel fromTCPSocket() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

My gateway class is as follows:

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "errorChannel")
public interface ClientGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel", replyChannel = "fromTCPSocket")
    Object sendAndRecieve(@Headers Object customHeaders, Object object);
}
```

and i invoke the gateway like this:

```
    public void handleRequest() {
    Map<String,Object> header = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    header.put("ip_connectionId", generateCorrelationId());
        gateway.sendAndRecieve(header,"Hello world");
}
```

And the exception that i am getting is following :

```
            2017-04-06 01:01:59.739 DEBUG 7460 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Got Connection localhost:8002:51561:d5c4ef5a-dffd-4e41-b724-600d30c6428a
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.751 DEBUG 7460 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : localhost:8002:51561:d5c4ef5a-dffd-4e41-b724-600d30c6428a Message sent GenericMessage [payload=Hello world, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, id=8cd8ff75-a4d3-d5b0-7290-b97e3f86d57c, ip_connectionId=af1ea8793d0cbde0, timestamp=1491420719710}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.751 DEBUG 7460 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] ssor$ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : handler 'TPSConfiguration.sendToStreamHost.serviceActivator.handler' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello world, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, id=8cd8ff75-a4d3-d5b0-7290-b97e3f86d57c, ip_connectionId=af1ea8793d0cbde0, timestamp=1491420719710}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.751 DEBUG 7460 --- [nio-9010-exec-1] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'requestChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=Hello world, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@79299208, id=8cd8ff75-a4d3-d5b0-7290-b97e3f86d57c, ip_connectionId=af1ea8793d0cbde0, timestamp=1491420719710}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.760 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.760 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : localhost:8002:51561:d5c4ef5a-dffd-4e41-b724-600d30c6428a Reading...
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.767 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : New connection 127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.767 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : createServerConectionFactory: Added new connection: 127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.770 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : 127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f Reading...
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.773 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer      : Available to read:0
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.774 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer      : Available to read:13
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.774 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'messageBuilderFactory'
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.775 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Message received GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=17e75c9d-2cfb-1d0d-4535-db95ceefee50, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719775}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.775 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'xmlToStringchannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=17e75c9d-2cfb-1d0d-4535-db95ceefee50, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719775}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.775 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@2e9f7f54] (TPSConfiguration.replyMessage.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=17e75c9d-2cfb-1d0d-4535-db95ceefee50, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719775}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.776 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.777 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationConversionService'
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.781 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'replyChannel'
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.781 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'replyChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=9b9eb07f-8829-67c1-e473-644a3d2883b0, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719781}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.781 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.integration.handler.BridgeHandler    : org.springframework.integration.handler.BridgeHandler@586e121d received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=9b9eb07f-8829-67c1-e473-644a3d2883b0, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719781}]
    2017-04-06 01:01:59.788 ERROR 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Exception sending message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[11], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=51561, ip_connectionId=127.0.0.1:51561:8002:61d62f47-77e7-473e-955c-e32585780b6f, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=17e75c9d-2cfb-1d0d-4535-db95ceefee50, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1491420719775}]

    org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.wrapExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.onMessage(TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:226) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted

    2017-04-06 01:01:59.788 DEBUG 7460 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.i.i.t.s.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer      : Available to read:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use `TcpOutboundGateway` for such a scenario.

The `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` and `TcpSendingMessageHandler` are using different sockets and there is no `replyChannel` information in the incoming message.

On the other hand I see a mess in your config. You declare `client` and server in the same context. Meanwhile it doesn't hurt, but can't be applied for your `@MessagingGateway` config. What I see here: you send message to the `client` and, yes, you receive it in the `server`, but your problem that you try to dispatch it into the `@MessagingGateway` reply. Confused...

Please, read more Spring Integration Reference Manual to understand how `@MessagingGateway` and TCP channel adapters work.

Comment: 1) Since i want Asynchronous process, I am using Channel-Adapters.
2) Are you suggesting to use AbstractClientConnectionFactory in both inbound and outbound channel adapters ?
3)I will set the reply channel info in the message header.
4) I will use the MessagingGateway to only send message to the outbound Channel adapter.

Thank you for quick reply. Please clarify 2nd point alone.

Comment: It won't work anyway. The `TemporaryReplyChannel` in headers for the MessagingGateway doesn't travel through the network. You have to sever you application for several to distinguish client and server.